# React Calender selects previous dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, next.js, react-calendar

I am trying to use React Calender package for my Next.js application for date picking. The problem that I have is that starting from the Month of October, from day 10th, each time I select a date, the previous date gets selected.
For instance, if I select 11th, it gets to display 10th as selected and when I console.log() it shows that it selected 10th.
This continues until December and from January, every date selected reflects properly.
I attached an image screen shot. I actually selected day 16 but it was day 15 that got selected and shown instead of day 16 that I clicked. When I console.log the output I found this:

```
Wed Oct 15 2025 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

How do I resolve this?
[image]

My codes so far:
The code where the initial date was generated:

```
  startDate:  dayjs(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
  endDate: dayjs(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

The calender component rendered like this:

```
  < Calendar
     value={dateState}
    onChange={(e)=>dateStateFunc(e, eventType, actionDependencies)}
   />
```

Where I used the calender component:

```
  < CustomDatePicker
    dateState={new Date(tripsData?.startDate)}
   />
```

Comment: Seems like a DST and timezone related problem. Perhaps the timezone is not set correctly in the component?

Comment: I am honestly using this for the first time. I have added sample code of how I called the component. Can you help me to check to see where I did something wrong?